# Trigonometric substitution $\tan{\frac{x}{2}}=t$. What is $\cos{x}$ then?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

For example, the integral is:
$$\int \frac{\sin{x}}{3\sin{x}+4\cos{x}}dx$$
And we use the substitution: $\tan{\frac{x}{2}}=t$
Now, to get $\cos{x}$ in terms of $\tan\frac{x}{2}$, I first expressed $\cos^2\frac{x}{2}$ and $\sin^2\frac{x}{2}$ in temrs of $\tan\frac{x}{2}$:
$$\cos^2\frac{x}{2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}+\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}}=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$$
$$\sin^2\frac{x}{2}=1-\cos^2\frac{x}{2}=1-\frac{1}{1+t^2}=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$$
Now, using trig idendity: $\cos{2x}=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}$ we have:
$$\cos{x}=\bigg(\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\bigg)=\frac{1}{1+t^2}-\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
which is good, but, I don't know what is wrong with this next procedure (first, getting $\sin^2{x}$, then using trig identity $\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}=1$ getting $\cos{x}$).
So, first, expressing $\sin{x}$ in terms of $\tan\frac{x}{2}$ using trig identity $\sin{2x}=2\sin{x}\cos{x}$:

$$\sin^2{x}=4\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\cos^2\frac{x}{2}=4\cdot\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+t^2}=\frac{4t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}$$
So:
$$\cos^2{x}=1-\sin^2{x}=1-\frac{4t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}=\frac{t^4-2t^2+1-4t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}=\frac{(t^2-1)^2}{(t^2+1)^2}$$
And, $\cos{x}$ is then:
$$\cos{x}=\pm\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}$$
Why do I get $\pm$ here? Did I make a mistake somewhere? Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is no minus sign. Relate $tan\frac{x}{2}=t$ in a right triangle. When doing Pythagorean theorem, you take the positive root here. Also, the num is $1-t^2$

Comment: Then I get $\cos{x}=\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}$ which is the opposite of what i got above: $\cos{x}=\frac{1-t^2}{t^2+1}$. The point is, I can write $(t^2-1)^2$ as $(1-t^2)^2$ and it's still the same.

Comment: When you place $tan\frac{x}{2}$ as an angle in a right triangle, it follows that the adjacent is $1$ and the opposite is $t$ by def of tangent. Using the Pythagorean Theorem, the hypostenuse is $\sqrt{1+t^2}$. Reading the sine and cosine from here gives a radical in the denom. Using the double angle formulas makes this radical go away to arrive at $sinx=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $cosx=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$. Also, I am missing the part of the differential in your story. What is $dt$ going to be?

Comment: $dt$ is $\frac{dx}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}$.

Comment: It should end up with $dx=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$, no $x$ terms anymore. On a side note: your integral can also be evaluated without all these substitutions, but just by some high school algebra...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather have a more elegant way to do this, but this way at least works:

You've shown that $\cos x = \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, and then that $\sin^2 x = \dfrac{4t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}$.

Notice that if you start with $a=b=3$ and then square both sides of $a=b$ to get $a^2=b^2$, you can deduce that $a = \pm b$.  That just means that either $a=b$ or $a=-b$; it doesn't mean $a$ is equal to both $b$ and $-b$.  So you must conclude that for each value of $x$, either $\sin x = \dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}$ or $\sin x = \dfrac{-2t}{1+t^2}$.  Might it be equal to that first expression for some values of $x$ and the second for others? If so, things would get somewhat more complicated.  But now look at the graphs of $x\mapsto\sin x$ and $x\mapsto \tan\dfrac x 2$ on the interval $-\pi\le x\le\pi$.  What you see is that $\sin x\ge0$ if $\tan\dfrac x 2\ge0$ and $\sin \le 0$ if $\tan\dfrac x 2\le 0$.  Consequently you have $\sin x = \dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}$ for all values of $x$.  Now compare the graphs of $x\mapsto\cos x$ and $x\mapsto \tan\dfrac x 2$ on that same interval, and observe that $\cos x\ge 0$ if $-1\le\tan \dfrac x 2\le 1$ and $\cos x\le 0$ if $\tan\dfrac x 2\ge 1$ or $\tan\dfrac x 2\le -1$.  That is the behavior of $\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and not of $-\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$. That decides between $\text{“}{+}\text{''}$ and $\text{“}{-}\text{''}$.

Comment: Incredible, thank you very much!

Comment: @A6SE : I'm glad it helped.  I would actually prefer a method that doesn't work piecewise.  Maybe I'll post something about that later. $\qquad$

Comment: I appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it's better to write $$\sin x=A(3\sin x+4\cos x)+B\cdot\dfrac{d(3\sin x+4\cos x)}{dx}$$

and find $A,B$ by comparing the coefficients $\sin x,\cos x$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

These are  well-known formulae :
$$\sin x =\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\qquad \cos x  =\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\qquad \tan x =\frac{2t}{1-t^2}\quad(t\not\equiv\pm\frac\pi4\mod\pi).$$

*A geometric proof of the formulae:*

Consider the unit circle and a line passing through the point $(-1,0)$which has equation $y=t(x+1)$. Let $M$ be the second interection point of the line with the circle. If $x$ is the polar angle of $M$, we have $t=\tan \frac x 2$, and the coordinates of $M$ are $\;x_M=\cos x,\enspace y_M=\sin x$. Now the equation for the abscissae of the intersection points is
$$(1+t^2)x_M^2+2t^2x_M+t^2-1=0,$$
of which one of the roots is $-1$, hence the other root, by *Viète's relations*, is $x_M=-\dfrac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}$. You obtain also
$\;\sin x=y_M=t\biggl(\dfrac{1-t^2}{t^2+1}+1\biggr)=\dfrac{2t}{t^2+1}$.

That said, *Bioche's rules* stipulate  you should set $u=\tan x$. Indeed, $\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=\dfrac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu u}{1+u^2}$, hence
$$I=\int \frac{\sin{x}}{3\sin{x}+4\cos{x}}\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=\int\frac{u}{3+4u^2}\dfrac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu u}{1+u^2}.$$
Decomposing into partial fractions:
$$\frac u{(3+4u^2)(1+u^2)}=\frac{4u}{3+4u^2}-\frac{u}{1+u^2},$$
we get
\begin{align*}I&=\frac12\bigl(\ln(3+4u^2)-\ln(1+u^2)\bigr)\\&= \frac12\ln\biggl(\frac{3+4\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}\biggr)=\frac12\ln(4-\cos^2x).
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question.  The question was not about how to evaluate the integral; rather it was about deriving the trigonometric identities, which you merely assert without derivations. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy: I mainly wanted to insist on the fact this is not the ‘good’ substitution. Anyway, I've added a geometric proof.